# Prestige loot box?

Tags: overwatch

If you hit prestige during an event (say Halloween or Summer Games), will you get the Event Loot box on hitting prestige or just normal loot boxes?

Comment: I'm confused - do you get extra loot boxes when prestige-ing or something?  If not, why would you think it's different from any other level-up?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft He's likely referring to the old prestige system when your exp per level would reset to 1 as well, meaning you get loot boxes faster. Sadly, this is no longer the case as every level past the plateau at prestige 0 (level.. 25?) is now a constant amount to the next level.

Comment: @KizTrap is correct. Blizzard specifically did this to prevent players from stop playing at level 99, 199, etc, so they may get fast loot boxes

Comment: @bmarkham Which is coincidentally exactly what I did during the halloween event. If I hadn't, I never would have got the Witch Mercy skin (in my last loot box of the season)

Answer (score 1):

The prestige level is just the same as a level up loot box. Some events will give you a loot box to highlight the fact that the lootbox are different for a certain period of time.

So no, all the loot box are born equal and the same during a time frame.